# Adding a controller function for the "home" view in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

When visiting a default CakePHP site, it takes you to "home.ctp" page.

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

I want to add a few elements there (like blog posts), so I thought I could just add this to the PagesController() class:

```
public function home() {
    $this->set('blogposts', $this->Blogpost->find('all'));
}
```

But that does not work.

So: what is the correct way to add something like this on the home page (or any other page for that matter)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The preferred option is to create a custom route for the home page but you can also override the PagesController's display function

Option 1: (Preferred Method)

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'myaction'));
```

Option 2

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'));
```

Option 3:

```
class PagesController {
    function display()
    {
        // default controller code here
        // your custom code here
    }
}
```

The final option is using requestAction in your view, but it isn't recommended as it has a huge performance drawback

Option 4: (Not recommended)

```
$newsitems = $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'newsitems', 'action' => 'getlatestnews', 'limit' => 10));
```

Comment: Ah yes, when using option 2 my custom function in the Pages controller is called. But it can't find $this->Blogpost.

Comment: Ah, using `$this->set('blogposts', ClassRegistry::init('Blogpost')->find('all'));` did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the action is `display`, `home` is a parameter. So your main method in the Controller Pages must call display, not home. After that, create `display.ctp` view.

Reference:

- [Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

To actually answer the original question:

```
$this->loadModel('Blogpost');
```

Ideally the model should be called

```
$this->loadModel('BlogPost');
```